# onScrolled gets automatically called during pagination

Tags: android, pagination, android-nestedscrollview

I have used `RecyclerView` inside `NestedScrollView` and after fetching data from api it automatically call `onScrolled` and increases page number. If I remove `NestedScrollView` then everything goes well so I want to know how to handle pagination in case of `NestedScrollView`. Also I have set `RecyclerView` to `setNestedScrollingEnabled` to false and used following logic:

```
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
    int visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
    int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
    int firstVisibleItemPosition = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

    if (!progressnotshowing && !islastpage) {
        if (visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition >= totalItemCount) {                       
            if (loadmore_send) {
                getcmntapi(++page_number);
                progressbar_mssgboardfullbottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressnotshowing = true;
            } else {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Try to put **RecyclerView** inside **FrameLayout** and test again.

```
<FrameLayout>
     <RecyclerView />
</FrameLayout>
```

If it does'nt work, try using Ultimate [Ultimate RecyclerView](https://github.com/cymcsg/UltimateRecyclerView). Hope to help you!

Comment: Nothing happen after adding framelayout, i still wonder what framelayout can do in this case ?